# NextJS URL params like React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I'm a newbie to [NextJS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js), It looks so good on the first impression.
But after giving it a chance I've faced some problems like URL routing with custom params like [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router).

#### Currently what We can do with NextJS

```
https://url.com/users?id:123
```

#### What We need to have for better URL pattern

```
https://url.com/users/123
```

In react-router It has perfect example here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Answer (score 44):

For anyone arriving late to this party, we now have [dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) in Next 9.

Which would allow for a url structure to be crafted like this by using the file structure, and without additional packages.

You could create a file `pages/user/[id].js`

With

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const User = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query

  return <p>User: {id}</p>
}

export default User
```

Comment: I am trying this but somehow router.query doesn't seem to return the id parameter. Can you please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885756/nextjs-catch-all-routes-on-root-level

Comment: Hi, the link to your question is broken. May I suggest you follow the online guide here: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes 
It covers what you ask about.

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking it out. it worked and it was some custom mistake so I deleted the question.

Comment: if i refresh the page, router.query become {} (empty), any clue why is it happening?

Answer (score 22):

## For older version: < 9.x

You can use `next/link`'s `as` feature:

```
<Link prefetch as={`/product/${slug}`} href={`/product?slug=${slug}`}>
```

Link on the browser will appear as `/product/slug` which internally maps to `/product?slug=slug`

You need to have a [custom server](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express) for server-side mapping:

```
server.get("/product/:slug", (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, "/product", { slug: req.params.slug })
})
```

## For 9.x and higher

Next 9.x supports [file system based dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes). You don't need a custom server anymore.

Next.js supports creating routes with basic named parameters, a pattern popularized by `path-to-regexp` (the library that powers [Express](https://expressjs.com/)).

Creating a page that matches the route `/product/:slug` can now be achieved by creating a file in your pages directory named: `pages/product/[slug].js`.

Multiple dynamic URL segments are also supported!

```
./pages/blog/[blogId]/comments/[commentId].js
./pages/posts/[pid]/index.js
```

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer. After a bit more searching I found this is how they tell you to do it in their docs. https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-dynamic-pages and the following two sections explain it in detail.

Comment: And how to achieve this

`/product/:slug/:commentId?/:someOtherOptionalParam?`

into nextjs format?

Comment: @SirajAlam if you have optionals, you can use [catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes).

`pages/product/[slug]/[...optionals].js` matches `/product/a`, but also `/product/a/b`, `/product/a/b/c` and so on.
Then you can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the optionals to get the `commentId` and other `optionalParams`.

Comment: @RashidulIslam, if you could answer this question with a bit explanation, I will mark you answer as accepted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625134/how-can-i-specify-the-optional-parameters-in-the-dynamic-routing

Answer (score 9):

## Problem: `query` Object Always Empty

**TL;DR: During first render, `query` is empty and `Router.isReady` is `false`. In all following render calls, everything is back to normal.**

In recent versions, [dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) is fully supported. The docs even show a super simple example of how it works. Sadly, for some reason, the docs fail to mention the important issue of hydration. This [blog post](https://dev.to/deepcodes/fixing-nextjs-router-query-param-returning-undefined-on-initial-render-5f80) explains some extra details.

The gist is: in many [dynamic rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) scenarios (including the default), during initial render on the client, the page first gets rendered without any parameters (probably due to hydration, based on a static state that cannot take the dynamic path into account).

### Solution

Allow your component to "kinda work" even if `router.query` is empty, e.g.:

```js
function MyComp() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  console.log(`[MyComp render] router.isReady=${router.isReady}, id=${id}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!router.isReady) {
      return;  // NOTE: router.query might be empty during initial render
    }

    doSomethingWithData(id);
  }, [id, router.isReady]);

  if (!router.isReady) {
    // we are still waiting for dynamic data to be available
    return 'loading...';
  }

  return theActualContent;
}
```

There even is the crucial `Router.isReady` field that tells you whether query data is available, but, for some reason, they do not mention it in the [`Dynamic Routes` documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

Answer (score 8):

First import Router

```
import Router from 'next/router'
```

Then if you want to use it in a Link tag

```
<Link href={{ pathname: '/about', query: { name: 'Sajad' } }}>
```

If you want to use it in a function or after a callback

```
Router.push({
    pathname: '/about',
    query: { name: 'Sajad' },
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the URL pattern https://url.com/users/123, where 123 is a dynamic parameter, you can use Next.js's built-in routing with parameterized routes.

First, create a file named [id].js inside the pages/users directory:

```
// pages/users/[id].js;
 import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function UserDetails() {

const router = useRouter();
const { id } = router.query;

return <div>User ID: {id}</div>;
}
export default UserDetails;
```