# Next.js cleans away query parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an app written in Next.js. I have a page like `my-page.jsx`. When I navigate to `/my-page?x=1&y=2` the page is rendered correctly and query-params are read. But the part of URL `?x=1&y=2` is being automatically removed. And this is a problem because when I navigate away from the page and then go *back* with a browser "back" button, then the query-params are no longer there and they are NOT read. So the page is rendred differenltly.

How can I prevent Next.js from removing the query-params from URL?

Comment: Do you use `<Link href=my-page?x=1&y=2" as="my-page?x=1&y=2">My Link</Link>` to navigate between pages ?

Comment: @dna I navigate both to and from page from completely different sites. The task involves complicated cross-site interaction. It's payment-related

Answer (score 0):

How are you hosting this app? Perhaps you haven't added a configuration to allow extra text outside the main URL. By default most hosts only allow you to access "www.example.com" and not "www.example.com/?x=1&y=2". Normally this would render an error page and not redirect you to "www.example.com".

Comment: It's hosted on a generic CentOS cloud instance with Nginx in front of it. The problem occurs even on localhost with nothing standing between a browser and a node.js process. I already told that query-params are successully read by the page. It's just that they are being removed from URL via client-side js right after that. The problem lies within Next.js client-side code. It's not a network/proxy problem.

Comment: @Gherman it looks like you might need to add a couple of steps. Perhaps this link might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181606/nextjs-url-params-like-react-router