# Reading URL Params NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am building a simple app where I would need to read the URL param and decipher it eg. `www.website.com/sa5d4a1d5sad`. I cannot figure out a way of getting that parameter.

I am looking through the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction). This might be an obvious question, but I cannot find a direct answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS URL params like React-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181606/nextjs-url-params-like-react-router)

Comment: Kind of. I guess I am confused because I only need the "/" route for the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const Value= () => 
{
    const router = useRouter();
    const {id} = router.query;
    console.log(router.query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the param from the exposed functions `getServerSideProps` `getStaticProps`:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const params = context.params
}
```

otherwise look at the above response.