# Pass data from index.tsx to to other pages

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a react app with the following code in `App.tsx`

```jsx
function App() {
  let date = new Date();
  // storing full name of all months in array
  const months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  const [currentMonth, SetCurrentMonth] = useState<string>(
    months[date.getMonth()]
  );
  const [currentYear, SetCurrentYear] = useState<number>(date.getFullYear());

  const changeMonth = (val: string) => {
    // if clicked icon is previous icon then decrement current month by 1 else increment it by 1
    if (val === "prev") {
      if (currentMonth === "January") {
        SetCurrentMonth(months[11]);
        SetCurrentYear((currentYear) => currentYear - 1);
      } else {
        SetCurrentMonth(months[months.indexOf(currentMonth) - 1]);
      }
    } else {
      if (currentMonth === "December") {
        SetCurrentMonth(months[0]);
        SetCurrentYear((currentYear) => currentYear + 1);
      } else {
        SetCurrentMonth(months[months.indexOf(currentMonth) + 1]);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <>
              <ViewSelector />
              <Summary
                monthNumber={months.indexOf(currentMonth)}
                month={currentMonth}
                year={currentYear}
                onClick={changeMonth}
              />
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/calendar/:player"
          element={
            <>
              <ViewSelector />
              <Calendar
                date={date}
                monthNumber={months.indexOf(currentMonth)}
                month={currentMonth}
                year={currentYear}
                onClick={changeMonth}
              />
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/manage"
          element={
            <>
              <ViewSelector />
              <Manage />
            </>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In React, we use `Routes` and `Route` to create routes and pass certain state variables (`currentMonth`, `currentYear`...) To the specific routes.

Now, I am trying to re-write this app in `Nextjs` but I am unable to figure out how I can pass, state variables (`currentMonth`, `currentYear`...) From the `index.tsx` to other pages (since they are separate `index.tsx` files in their respective folders).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS URL params like React-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181606/nextjs-url-params-like-react-router)

Comment: @devpolo I do not think so. I want to pas the value of the state variable to different pages (the state is managed in only one file)